# Calling notifydatasetchange for one adapter from another adapter

Tags: android, listview, listadapter, onclicklistener, baseadapter

In my activity I have two listviews and so I am using two different adapters. My requirement is in both the list item I have a button. On clicking the button in any of the listview, the data in both the listview should change. Now the problem is how do I access the adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() for one adapter in the click of button in another adapter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply in your onClick method

```
public void onClick(View v)
{
 adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
 adapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

and if you are using the button in your listview's row then you should do this in your getView() method

```
@Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View row=convertView;
        if(row==null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater=((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
            row=inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent,false);

            holder=new YourHodler();
            holder.button=(Button)row.findViewById(R.id.bt);


            row.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder=(YourHolder)row.getTag();
        }

        holder.button.setOnClickListner(new View.onClickListener()
                {
                   //update your Any data set which is beign attached to both the adapters
                   //for example if you are using List<Collection> then you should first
                   //update it or change it
                   //then
                   adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
                   adapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

        return row;
    }
```

Comment: I have a different class for both the adapter

Comment: no problem simply update both dataset that are beign attached to both classes and you are done

Comment: did you got me or need more clarification

Comment: i guess you are implementing some sort of this
`1.List<Class1> list1=new ArrayList<Class1>();`
`2.List<Class2> list2=new ArrayList<Class2>();`
simply update the lists you want to update in your onClick() method and call adaoter.notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: simply update dataset? I have 2 different array adapter which I am passing to two different classes of list adapter

Comment: then you can static refrence to access the objects of your adapter

Comment: I will do that tomorrow from my work place. Thanks for your help

Comment: I have made my adapter class as inner class and made the adapter object as a class member object. Now I am able to access adapters any where. This has solved my issues. :)

Comment: @ShaistaNaaz oh thats gud to hear because its my first answer to stack overflow and i worth it :)

Comment: it is not necessary to make adapter class as inner to access,you can access any object from any other class by declaring it as **static**

Comment: adapter1 and adapter2 are 2 different classes and each of them have a button. These buttons are different and have different ids(obvious). How do I access adapter1 in the click of button in adapter2 and adapter2 in the click of button in adapter1. They both do not know each other as they don't have each other's instance.

Comment: simply declare your declare your adapter static you can access it in your button click in any other adapter.just try it it will work definitely

Comment: thanks but I don't my adapter to be static, it has its owns cons if I make it static it will hold the context of the activity. And even if my activity goes out of scope adapter will still hold the context. this leaves chance of memory leak. So i will prefer making my adapter as inner class after all it is not doing any harm.

Comment: Adapter Classes are never extended by Activity!!

Comment: you need context of the activity in the adapter constructor

Comment: in your activity call your adapter like new SomeAdapter(this);

Comment: you will get the context and can use it

Answer (score 0):

Implement a method that does the following in your activity:

```
CustomActivity1 extends Activity {
....
//make it public
public void updateLists() {
   CustomAdapter1 adapter1 = (CustomAdapter1) ((ListView) findViewById(R.id.list1)).getListAdapter();
   CustomAdapter2 adapter2 = (CustomAdapter2) ((ListView) findViewById(R.id.list2)).getListAdapter();

   //update the adapters
   adapter1.notifyDatasetChanged();
   adapter2.notifyDatasetChanged();
}
....
}
```

in order for the custom adapters to function you must pass an `Activity` context. So the onclick listener in both of your adapters you can add something like:

```
CustomAdapter1 { //and in CustomAdapter2 
....
private OnClickListener ButtonClick = new OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(View v) {
         //...your code             
         //having the context of the CustomActivity1 stored in a variable from the constructor you can simply do:
         customActivity1Context.updateLists();
     }
}
....
}
```

Comment: I can do .notifyDatasetChanged() only in the button click and that button is defined inside the adapter class. And both the adapters are different class so they don't have instance of each other.

Comment: I have updated my answer. No need to make inner classes or static methods. Just make the method you want public and access it from whenever you want by the activity's context in both adapters.